# Pass String from One class to another class

Tags: java, class

I have this 1st clas:

```
 private class proceedAL implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z)
    {
        String x = (String)mouseB.getActionCommand();
        String y = (String)monitorB.getActionCommand();
        ComputerSimulator me = new connect(x,y);
    }

}
```

and another class:

```
public class ComputerSimulator extends JFrame
{
public void connect(String x, String y)
{
   String i, j;
   c2.setText(x);
   c3.setText(y);
}
```

---

This error appears: cannot find symbol - class connect

What am I missing? I'm just a starter in Programming, need some help guys

Comment: don't throw string, pass it! it is more kind =)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to instantiate an object of your class and call its method is this:

```
ComputerSimulator e = new ComputerSimulator();
e.connect(x, y);
```

Answer (score 2):

`connect` indeed is not class. It is a method in class `ComputerSimulator`.

You should create object first:

`ComputerSimulator me = new ComputerSimulator()`

now you can call method `connect`: `me.connect(x, y);`

Answer (score 0):

`connect` is not a class, its a **method** on the class `ComputerSimulator`.  You are invoking the `connect` method as if it were the constructor, you need to do

```
ComputerSimulator computerSimulator = new ComputerSimulator();
computerSimulator.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having it wrong, you can only make `new` of a class (like `ComputerSimulator`).

Once you have an instance of that class, you can use its public methods (like `connect`) -> `me.connect(x, y);`

By the way, `throws` refers only to exception handling.